# Как на Objective-C создать динамический массив строк?

Tags: objective-c, консоль, macos

Взял число из потока ввода:

```
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
```

Как теперь на Objective-C создать динамический массив строк из ix3 элементов и записать в него ix3 строк. 
К примеру на С++ это выглядит так:

```
string *sName = new string[i*3];
for(int iRead = 0; iRead < i*3; ++iRead)
   cin >> sName[iRead];
```

Comment: Судя по вашим вопросам вы лучше знаете си++, так и пишите на нем, также вполне допускается комбинировать C++ c obj-c, нужно только файлу расширение сменить на mm чтобы сборщик понял что за файл перед ним

Comment: Так я специально перевожу программы с С++ на Objective-C. Использую это как один из способов изучения Objective-C. К тому же, приводя пример на С++, это помогает уточнить вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    [mutableArray addObject:@"Lol"];
}
NSLog(@"Array: %@",mutableArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете вызвать метод [initWithCapacity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1460057-arraywithcapacity?language=objc), который вернет массив с уже выделенной памятью под нужное количество элементов.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:k];
```